# Selenium Webdriver: what is root logger and manual logger in log4j

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, log4j

I have recently come across this line of code and i read that root logger is for system generated code

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,file
```

where as

```
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
```

this for application logs, this will help log information generated by manual code.

Can you please explain the difference between application logs and system generated logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you know how logs are configured for log4j. If not then open this  [link](http://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html) and follow the **How log4j is configured?**

Now coming back to your question that what is the difference between APPLICATION LOGS and SYSTEM GENERATED LOGS.

**Application Logs:** 
The application log is a tool that collects messages, exceptions & errors from an application. This information is organized and displayed in a log

**System Logs:**
The system logs for every important action like system errors, warnings, user locks, & process message etc. in the system log

**Difference:**
Application logging records the progress of the execution of an application, whereas the system log record system events.

I hope this answers your question.